# How many ways to achieve a multiple of $5$ numbers between $1$ and $8$ which are not unique?

Tags: combinatorics

This question comes from the Faridpur Olympiad $2017$.

[image]

Text:

> $9)$ The numbers $1$ to $8$ are written on seven balls. Miyad took five balls from there such that if he multiplies the numbers of the balls and then say it to Mursalin, then Mursalin can't say the number of the balls surely. How many ways can Miyad do this?

**My attempt:**
I noticed that it was only possible if Mursalin is confused between:

$1) \ (a,b,c, 1, 8)$ and $(a,b,c, 2, 4)$
$2) \ (a,b,c, 2, 3)$ and $(a,b,c, 1, 6)$
$3) \ (a,b,c, 4, 3)$ and $(a,b,c, 2, 6)$
$4) \ (a,b,c, 8, 3)$ and $(a,b,c, 4, 6)$

Is there any other case? How can I calculate the number of possible combinations? Also, the part about "(t)he numbers $1$ to $8$ are written on seven balls" confuses me. Is it supposed to be eight balls?

Comment: The statement, "The numbers $1$ to $8$ are written on seven balls," seems ambiguous to me.  Does it mean that one of the numbers is missing?  Does is mean that each number is written on seven different balls?  Is it supposed to say eight balls?  I don't see how to tell.

Comment: Nor do I which is why I included the image. The bengali suggests that one number is skipped at random. However, I don't see how choosing 5 out of 7 is different from choosing 5 out of 8.